# ImageCollection (Error) Error in map: Image.constant: Parameter 'value' is required

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, sentinel-1

I need to use data from Sentinel-1 satellite to extract water bodies and obtain water area, but I encountered an error during terrain correction: ImageCollection (Error)
Error in map: Image. constant: Parameter 'value' is required.

I don't know how to solve it. This is my code https://code.earthengine.google.com/d8ad840ae015257abd2ea37e8da28270

```
var aoi=ee.FeatureCollection('users/huangliuhong227/try1buffer')
var styling = {color:"red",fillColor:"00000000"};
Map.addLayer(aoi,{color:"red",fillColor:"00000000"},"aoi")
var roi = aoi.geometry().bounds();
var styling = {color:"red",fillColor:"00000000"};
Map.addLayer(roi,{color:"red",fillColor:"00000000"},"aoi")
Map.centerObject(aoi, 12);

var start = '2019-1-1';
var end = '2019-1-31';

var s1_collection = ee.ImageCollection('COPERNICUS/S1_GRD')
                    .filterBounds(aoi)
                    .filterDate(start, end)
                    .filter(ee.Filter.listContains('transmitterReceiverPolarisation', 'VV'))
                    .filter(ee.Filter.eq('instrumentMode', 'IW'))
                    //.filter(ee.Filter.eq('orbitProperties_pass', 'ASCENDING'))
                    //.map(function(image){return image.clip(aoi)})//.clip(Map.getBounds(true))})
                    .map(function(image){return image.addBands(image.select('VV').focal_median(parseFloat('50'),'circle','meters').rename('VV_smoothed'))}); // Smooth S1-Images

print('Original S1 collection',s1_collection)

var s1Collection = s1_collection.map(function(img){
  // unmask each image in the collection
  var unmasked = img.unmask(-99).eq(-99);
  // reduce histogram on each image and set the keys as properties (key '1' will be masked pixels)
  var rR = unmasked.reduceRegion({reducer: ee.Reducer.frequencyHistogram(),
                              geometry: img.geometry(),
                              scale: 100,
                              bestEffort: true});
  var newProperties = ee.Dictionary(rR.get('VV'));
  return img.set(newProperties)
  
})
var CleanS1Collection = ee.ImageCollection(s1Collection).filter(ee.Filter.notNull(['0'])).map(function(image){return image.clip(Map.getBounds(true))})//.clip(aoi)})//,clip(roi/aoi)
print('Clean S1 Collection',CleanS1Collection);

// Implementation by Andreas Vollrath (ESA), inspired by Johannes Reiche (Wageningen)
function terrainCorrection(image) { 
  var imgGeom = image.geometry();
  var srtm = ee.Image('USGS/SRTMGL1_003').clip(imgGeom); // 30m srtm 
  var sigma0Pow = ee.Image.constant(10).pow(image.divide(10.0));

  // Article ( numbers relate to chapters) 
  // 2.1.1 Radar geometry 
  var theta_i = image.select('angle');
  var phi_i = ee.Terrain.aspect(theta_i)
    .reduceRegion(ee.Reducer.mean(), theta_i.get('system:footprint'), 1000)
    .get('aspect');

  // 2.1.2 Terrain geometry
  var alpha_s = ee.Terrain.slope(srtm).select('slope');
  var phi_s = ee.Terrain.aspect(srtm).select('aspect');

  // 2.1.3 Model geometry
  // reduce to 3 angle
  var phi_r = ee.Image.constant(phi_i).subtract(phi_s);

  // convert all to radians
  var phi_rRad = phi_r.multiply(Math.PI / 180);
  var alpha_sRad = alpha_s.multiply(Math.PI / 180);
  var theta_iRad = theta_i.multiply(Math.PI / 180);
  var ninetyRad = ee.Image.constant(90).multiply(Math.PI / 180);

  // slope steepness in range (eq. 2)
  var alpha_r = (alpha_sRad.tan().multiply(phi_rRad.cos())).atan();

  // slope steepness in azimuth (eq 3)
  var alpha_az = (alpha_sRad.tan().multiply(phi_rRad.sin())).atan();

  // local incidence angle (eq. 4)
  var theta_lia = (alpha_az.cos().multiply((theta_iRad.subtract(alpha_r)).cos())).acos();
  var theta_liaDeg = theta_lia.multiply(180 / Math.PI);
  // 2.2 
  // Gamma_nought_flat
  var gamma0 = sigma0Pow.divide(theta_iRad.cos());
  var gamma0dB = ee.Image.constant(10).multiply(gamma0.log10());
  var ratio_1 = gamma0dB.select('VV').subtract(gamma0dB.select('VH'));

  // Volumetric Model
  var nominator = (ninetyRad.subtract(theta_iRad).add(alpha_r)).tan();
  var denominator = (ninetyRad.subtract(theta_iRad)).tan();
  var volModel = (nominator.divide(denominator)).abs();

  // apply model
  var gamma0_Volume = gamma0.divide(volModel);
  var gamma0_VolumeDB = ee.Image.constant(10).multiply(gamma0_Volume.log10());

  // we add a layover/shadow maskto the original implmentation
  // layover, where slope > radar viewing angle 
  var alpha_rDeg = alpha_r.multiply(180 / Math.PI);
  var layover = alpha_rDeg.lt(theta_i);

  // shadow where LIA > 90
  var shadow = theta_liaDeg.lt(85);

  // calculate the ratio for RGB vis
  var ratio = gamma0_VolumeDB.select('VV').subtract(gamma0_VolumeDB.select('VH'));

  var output = gamma0_VolumeDB.addBands(ratio).addBands(alpha_r).addBands(phi_s).addBands(theta_iRad)
    .addBands(layover).addBands(shadow).addBands(gamma0dB).addBands(ratio_1);

  return image.addBands(
    output.select(['VV', 'VH'], ['VV', 'VH']),
    null,
    true
  );
}
var tcS1 = CleanS1Collection.map(terrainCorrection)
          
print('tcS1',tcS1)

//Otsu
var otsu = function(histogram) {
var counts = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(histogram).get('histogram'));
var means = ee.Array(ee.Dictionary(histogram).get('bucketMeans'));
var size = means.length().get([0]);
var total = counts.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
var sum = means.multiply(counts).reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
var mean = sum.divide(total);
var indices = ee.List.sequence(1, size);
var bss = indices.map(function(i) {
var aCounts = counts.slice(0, 0, i);
var aCount = aCounts.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0]);
var aMeans = means.slice(0, 0, i);
var aMean = aMeans.multiply(aCounts)
.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum(), [0]).get([0])
.divide(aCount);
var bCount = total.subtract(aCount);
var bMean = sum.subtract(aCount.multiply(aMean)).divide(bCount);
return aCount.multiply(aMean.subtract(mean).pow(2)).add(
      bCount.multiply(bMean.subtract(mean).pow(2)));
});
// print(ui.Chart.array.values(ee.Array(bss), 0, means));
return means.sort(bss).get([-1]);
};

var add_waterMask = function(image){
  
  // Compute histogram
  var histogram = image.select('VV').reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.histogram(255, 2)
      .combine('mean', null, true)
      .combine('variance', null, true), 
    geometry: aoi, 
    scale: 10,
    bestEffort: true
  });
  
  // Calculate threshold via function otsu (see before)
    var threshold = otsu(histogram.get('VV_histogram'));
    
  // get watermask 
  var waterMask = image.select('VV').lt(threshold).rename('waterMask');
  waterMask = waterMask.updateMask(waterMask); //Remove all pixels equal to 0.rename('waterMask')//
  return image.addBands(waterMask);
};
var s1_add_waterMask = tcS1.map(add_waterMask);
print('s1_add_waterMask',s1_add_waterMask)

//calculateWaterArea
var calculateWaterArea = function(image) {
  
  //  waterMask
  var = image.select('waterMask');
  
  var waterArea = waterMask.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: aoi,
    scale: 10,
    bestEffort: true
  });
  
  image = image.set('waterArea_sqm', waterArea.get('waterMask'));
    return image;
};

var calculateWaterArea = function(image) {

  var waterMask = image.select('waterMask');
  
  var waterArea = waterMask.multiply(ee.Image.pixelArea()).reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum(),
    geometry: aoi,
    scale: 10,
    bestEffort: true
  });
  
  var waterGeometry = waterMask.reduceToVectors({
    geometry: aoi,
    scale: 10,
    eightConnected: false,
    labelProperty: 'water'
  });
  
  image = image.set('waterArea_sqm', waterArea.get('waterMask'));
  image = image.set('waterGeometry', waterGeometry);
  
  return image;
};

var S2_withWaterArea = s1_add_waterMask.map(calculateWaterArea);

print('S2_withWaterArea', S2_withWaterArea);

// Function to format date to YYYYMMDD
var formatDate = function(date) {
  var year = ee.Number(ee.Date(date).get('year')).format('%04d');
  var month = ee.Number(ee.Date(date).get('month')).format('%02d');
  var day = ee.Number(ee.Date(date).get('day')).format('%02d');
  return ee.String(year).cat(month).cat(day);
};

// Export water area information to CSV
var exportWaterAreaCSV = function(image) {
  var date = image.date();
  var formattedDate = formatDate(date);
  var waterArea = image.get('waterArea_sqm');
  
  // Print the formatted date and water area
  //print('Date:', formattedDate, 'Water Area (sqm):', waterArea);
  
  // Return a feature with properties for export
  return ee.Feature(null, {
    'Date': formattedDate,
    'Water_Area_sqm': waterArea
  });
};

// Apply the export function to the S2_withWaterArea collection
var waterAreaFeatures = S2_withWaterArea.map(exportWaterAreaCSV);

// Create a feature collection from the features
var waterAreaFeatureCollection = ee.FeatureCollection(waterAreaFeatures);

// Export the feature collection to a CSV file
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: waterAreaFeatureCollection,
  description: 'water_area_info',
  fileFormat: 'CSV'
});
```